# Cocos2dx (version : cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2) No libcocos2d.so, libbox2d.so, libcocosdenshion made

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio-2010, cocos2d-x

I made a sample project on Windows 7, Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 with a background and sound playing on loop . It builds, compiles and runs fine in VS 2010.

But when I am trying to compile it for Android, it compiles fine with no errors. But when I import it in the Eclipse Juno workspace, I see only libgame.so in the libs->armeabi folder.

Unlike the previous versions, there is no  libcocos2d.so, libbox2d.so, libcocosdenshion.so made.

> static {
>            System.loadLibrary("game");
>           }

The application runs fine, but I **CANNOT** hear sound like in Windows build ? I think I need to add cocosdenshion library but it is not made.

I do see libcocos2d.a, libbox2d.a, libcocosdenshion.a in obj->local->armeabi folder. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem so that I can hear sound ?

P.S. I think its a problem of shared and static libraries. In previous versions of cocos2dx these libraries were shared and now they are static.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem through recompiling.

In the new version we don't need to add any library libcocos2d.so, libbox2d.so, libcocosdenshion.so

static { System.loadLibrary("game"); } works fine.